# Android, adding a varying number of clickable spans to a textview

Tags: android, html, string, android-intent, click

So I have been working on a project to add a feature found on iOS, wherein I can analyze a textfield for certain key word-types, in this case references to dates, and highlight them so that they are clickable and launch a new activity with an intent, in this case launching the calendar to the mentioned date.  I have finished a program that can extract desired word groups and provide their index values in the origin string and a long of the related date in milliseconds to use for the intent.

What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to dynamically add the correct spannable strings to the textfield so that I have a place to store the onClick action associated from each object in my program.  If there were a static number of highlighted objects I could write a finite number of spannable strings to create, but in this instance the program may find one relevant date keyword or it may find 50.  I don't know how to create a spannable string for each index range my program turns out and associate a click-action with each one.

Example:

Original string: "Would you like to have dinner next Tuesday?"

Program finds: "next Tuesday" start: 30 end: 43 time:1445947214457

Desired reformat: "Would you like to have dinner **next Tuesday**?" //clickable

Answer (score 1):

You would only have one `SpannableString`. You would have many spans in that `SpannableString`.

For example, the following method is from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RichText/Search):

```
  private void searchFor(String text) {
    TextView prose=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prose);
    Spannable raw=new SpannableString(prose.getText());
    BackgroundColorSpan[] spans=raw.getSpans(0,
                                             raw.length(),
                                             BackgroundColorSpan.class);

    for (BackgroundColorSpan span : spans) {
      raw.removeSpan(span);
    }

    int index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text);

    while (index >= 0) {
      raw.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF8B008B), index, index
          + text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text, index + text.length());
    }

    prose.setText(raw);
  }
```

Here, I am finding substring matches for a given search string and highlighting them with a `BackgroundColorSpan`. I do not know how many such matches there will be. I create a `BackgroundColorSpan` for each. In your case, your "search" criteria will be different, as will the spans, but the basic approach should be the same.

Comment: So the only thing this doesn't clear up for me is how I can attach click listeners for each span.  Setting hyperlink formatting or whatever will function exactly the same as in this example, but I also have to pair each span with an independent time that it has to point to. I could probably create some sort of object where the time is a property of the span, but I don't know how to keep the processed span pointing at its time.

Comment: @GraysonGould: "how I can attach click listeners for each span" -- your spans would be some custom subclass of `ClickableSpan`, presumably. "I don't know how to keep the processed span pointing at its time" -- use a field in your `ClickableSpan` subclass.